# How to combine multiple QueryDescriptor in hibernate elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I am new to hibernate elastic search. I have gone through the official document and I found, to get the data from elastic search I have to write following code.

```
FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
QueryDescriptor query = ElasticsearchQueries.fromQueryString("title:tales");
List<?> result = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query, ComicBook.class).list();
```

But I am trying to understand how can I combine multiple QueryDescriptor into BooleanJunction as it is only taking lucene query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ElasticsearchQueries.fromQueryString` is a way to avoid the Hibernate Search DSL, which includes `BooleanJunction` in particular. You can use `ElasticsearchQueries.fromQueryString`, or the Hibernate Search DSL, but not both in the same query.

If you really want to stick with `ElasticsearchQueries.fromQueryString`, this becomes a problem of understanding the syntax of Elasticsearch queries. Something like that should do the trick

```
FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
QueryDescriptor query = ElasticsearchQueries.fromQueryString("title:tales AND someOtherField:someOtherValue");
List result = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query, ComicBook.class).list();
```

You can have a look at the Elasticsearch documentation for more information on the syntax: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

Note that, unless your queries are particularly complex, you shouldn't need to use `ElasticsearchQueries.fromQueryString`; the Hibernate Search DSL should work equally well, and may spare you some time trying to fix your queries (because you would use Java code, which is mostly checked at compile time, instead of String queries validated at runtime). More information on the Query DSL can be found here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-query